# Should I check for a element on a page before calling the Jquery plugin or call it and allow it to fail if not there

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have recently been wondering what would be the most friendly/efficient way to use plugins that have been bundled together to leverage caching. Are plugins are tied to HTML modules that are used sporadically in the site and have been called by using this kind of pattern:

```
if($('.moduleClass').length) {
   $('.moduleClass').modulePlugin();
}
```

So we check for the module before we call the plugin. I have been wondering if this is the best solution or should I just be allowing jQuery to handle the fail if the browser doesn't find the element.

```
$('.moduleClass').modulePlugin();
```

Any idea, thoughts and experiences would be greatly received.

Thanks,

Ad

Comment: If the plugin is coded properly then not checking is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing 2 DOM lookups, is slower than doing 1.

Let jQuery handle it, there shouldn't be an error if there are no elements with the class 'moduleClass', nothing should happen.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not checking for existing explicitly. Just try to find a DOM element and call methods on it. Even if the element does not exist. jQuery handles this for you.

About speed: You're doing two DOM lookups in your first example, which is obviously slower than your second example. And even if you cached the jQuery object in the first example, it's still one lookup in each example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, from the start, you're already calling `.length` on what could have been an empty set. jQuery lets you do that because it handles stuff like non-existent elements correctly.

Now, whether or not your plugin does the same is a whole different question. Nonetheless, I recommend against checking first anyway. If the plugin does not handle empty sets properly (especially since jQuery -- which it's built on -- **does**), I'd think again about using it.

Answer (score 0):

I learned that if the plugin sucks it makes sense to check for it. 
But if the plugin itself does a check via length or each(). There is nothing to gain by checking with length.